# Write a function sum13(nums)

Tags: python

Write a function sum13(nums) that takes a list of ints nums and returns the sum of the numbers in the list, returning 0 for an empty list. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count.

```
Test    Result
print(sum13([1, 2, 2, 1, 13]))
6
print(sum13([13, 2, 2, 1]))
3
print(sum13([13, 13, 2, 13, 1, 5, 6, 13]))
11(EXPECTED)
13(GOT)
```

here is my program I don't know why the last test code is not running

```
def sum13(nums):
    """jdhdjkls"""
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return 0

    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 13:
            nums[i] = 0
            if i+1 < len(nums): 
                nums[i+1] = 0
    return sum(nums)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: What happens if you have two 13 in a row?

Comment: Well, anytime you see a 13, you set it to a zero, and you immediately also set the following number to a zero - even if the following number is another 13.

Comment: As a result, 2 is *not* zeroed out, because it follows a 0, not a 13, by the time you examine the 2nd element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) method to zip two lists skewed like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

to

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4, None]
```

and check to see if any of the pairs have `13` in them.

**Here is how:**

```
def sum13(nums):
    s = 0 if nums[0] == 13 else nums[0]
    for p in zip(nums, nums[1:]):
        if all(n != 13 for n in p):
            s += p[1]
    return s

print(sum13([1, 2, 2, 1, 13]))
print(sum13([13, 2, 2, 1]))
print(sum13([13, 13, 2, 13, 1, 5, 6, 13]))
```

Output:

```
6
3
11
```

**You can also unpack the pairs:**

```
def sum13(nums):
    s = 0 if nums[0] == 13 else nums[0]
    for i, j in zip(nums, nums[1:]):
        if i != 13 != j:
            s += j
    return s

print(sum13([1, 2, 2, 1, 13]))
print(sum13([13, 2, 2, 1]))
print(sum13([13, 13, 2, 13, 1, 5, 6, 13]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
def sum13(nums):
    """jdhdjkls"""
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return 0

    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 13:
            nums[i] = 0
            # problem arises when there are 2 consecutive 13 this if statement will rectify it.
            if (i+1 < len(nums)) and (nums[i+1]!=13): 
                nums[i+1] = 0
    return sum(nums)
```

Comment: This doesn't compile nor run due to a `num` vs. `nums` typo.  Otherwise fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts can't correspond to `13 13 2` because they are made `0 0 2` in first step.

`for` and `continue` is effective for your goal.

```
def sum13(nums):
    sums=0
    after13=False
    for num in nums:
        if num == 13:
            after13=True
            continue
        if not after13:
            sums+=num
        after13=False
    return sums
```

Comment: This returns 5 for `[13, 2, 2, 1]` instead of 3 which the OP's rules imply.  Ditto for other examples.

Answer (score 0):

We could try using *recursion* to solve this problem:

```
def sum13(numbers):
    if not numbers:  # base case
        return 0

    first, *rest = numbers

    if first == 13:
        first = 0

        if rest and rest[0] != 13:
            rest.pop(0)

    return first + sum13(rest)

print(sum13([1, 2, 2, 1, 13]))
print(sum13([13, 2, 2, 1]))
print(sum13([13, 13, 2, 13, 1, 5, 6, 13]))
```

Though not the style of answer you likely want, we can also coerce `itertools.groupby` to do the work for us:

```
from itertools import groupby

def sum13(numbers):
    previous13 = False

    def is_tainted(number):
        nonlocal previous13

        tainted = previous13
        previous13 = number == 13

        return True if tainted else previous13

    total = 0

    for tainted, subset in groupby(numbers, is_tainted):
        if not tainted:
            total += sum(subset)

    return total
```

Comment: The first time seeing `nonlocal`! I'll look it up.

Comment: I like the creative approaches! ;) There's a typo in the first one, though, you meant `if rest and rest[0] == 13:` - or you can just drop the whole `if` block, any 13 in `rest` will be taken care of by the next recursive call anyway.

Comment: And there's a problem a well in the second version: `sum13([13, 13, 3, 3])` returns `3`...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, I didn't make a typo in my first example, that's the way it works.  And as far as the second example, 3 is the correct answer, as the instructions imply, and as all the other posted answers return.  I don't see your example that does otherwise.